# Convert number to varchar using to_varchar with leading zeros in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake there is a number column storing values like:  8,123,456.  I am struggling determining how to structure select statement to return a value like: 00008123456.

In SQL SERVER you can do something like this:

```
right(replicate('0', 11) + convert(varchar(11), job_no), 11) AS job_no
```

I understand Snowflake to_varchar function can be used, but not sure how to structure like in SQL Server.

Comment: What's the datatype of the column in question?

Comment: In any case: [`LPAD`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a format string on to_varchar():

```
select to_varchar(8123456, '00000000000');
```

Comment: sweet - nice one

Answer (score 1):

Give it try with:

```sql
SELECT LPAD('12234.50', 19, '0');

/* RETURNS 19 Positions including the decimal point. */
-- 0000000000012234.50
```

More examples & details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

a solution provided by Greg Pavlik saved me.
I just switched from DB2 to Snowflake.

So, `TO_VARCHAR( <numeric_expr> [, '<format>' ] )` worked.